# Least Squares C# library

Tags: c#, math, numerical

I am looking to perform a polynomial least squares regression and am looking for a C# library to do the calculations for me.

I pass in the data points and the degree of polynomal (2nd order, 3rd order, etc)  and it returns either the C0, C1, C2 etc. constant values or the calculated values "predictions".

Note: I am using Least Squares to create some forecasting reports for disk usage, database size and table size.

Comment: [Link for my linear least squares solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18618362/2239678)
Simple API that solves the linear least squares problem.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a link for C# code on to do exactly this: http://www.trentfguidry.net/post/2009/08/01/Linear-Regression-of-Polynomial-Coefficients.aspx

Good luck!

**Edit:** Apparently the above link is broken. I made another solution awhile back: http://procbits.com/2011/05/02/linear-regression-in-c-sharp-least-squares/

Comment: If so, I coded up a solution: http://procbits.com/2011/05/02/linear-regression-in-c-sharp-least-squares/

Comment: I found a link to the original C# code on archive.org here http://web.archive.org/web/20091004001612/http://www.trentfguidry.net/post/2009/08/01/Linear-Regression-of-Polynomial-Coefficients.aspx ... it works perfectly, and all the sub-linked articles which are required are all present.

Comment: @JP forgive my ignorance but isn't your solution just a simple linear regression (i.e. y = a + bx). I think the OP needed a polynomial curve fit such as y = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @dodgy_coder yes, you're correct. I'm not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @BMW I agree. When I answered this question 4 years ago, I think the standards may have been different. But I honestly don't remember. Do you think it'd be prudent for me to paste in the code from my old blog post?

Comment: I just realised, that's  4 years old answer. It will be good if you can update with detail.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case you want an "optimizer" or "mimimizer". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(mathematics)#Solvers for some exmples. I see that the first link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMSL_Numerical_Libraries) claims to have c# support.

---

Edit: For the limited use that you propose (linear or quadratic polynomials), you could just go to any copy of Numerical Recipies, grab a straight ahead implementation, and translate to your language. A general minimizer is overkill.

But note, also, that polynomials may be poor predictors.

Answer (score 1):

You can check library form ALGLIB under GPL licence 2.0.  They have source code for C#, C++,...

http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/leastsquares.php

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/linearleastsquares.php).  It is in C++ instead of C#, but you might be able to write a wrapper over it.

Comment: I just noticed Alglib supports C# library, with 100% managed code.