# C# Linear Interpolation

Tags: c#, interpolation

I'm having issues interpolating a data file, which i have converted from .csv into an X array and Y array where X[0] corresponds to point Y[0] for example.

I need to interpolate between the values to give me a smooth file at the end.
I am using a Picoscope to output the function which means each line is equally spaced in time, so only using Y values, which is why I'm trying to do this in a strange way when you see my code.

The kind of values it has to deal with are:

```
X     Y
0     0
2.5   0
2.5   12000
7.5   12000
7.5   3000
10    3000
10    6000
11    6625.254
12    7095.154
```

So where 2 Y values next to each other are the same its a straight line between them but when they vary like from X = 10 on wards it becomes a sine wave in this example.

I have been looking at the equations for interpolation etc and other posts on here but i haven't done that sort of maths for years and sadly i can't figure it out any more, because there's 2 unknowns and i can't think how to program that into c#.

What i have is:

```
int a = 0, d = 0, q = 0;
bool up = false;
double times = 0, change = 0, points = 0, pointchange = 0; 
double[] newy = new double[8192];
while (a < sizeoffile-1 && d < 8192)
{
    Console.Write("...");
    if (Y[a] == Y[a+1])//if the 2 values are the same add correct number of lines in to make it last the correct time
    {
        times = (X[a] - X[a + 1]);//number of repetitions
        if ((X[a + 1] - X[a]) > times)//if that was a negative number try the other way around
            times = (X[a + 1] - X[a]);//number of repetitions 
        do
        {
            newy[d] = Y[a];//add the values to the newy array which replaces y later on in the program
            d++;//increment newy position
            q++;//reduce number of reps in this loop
        }
        while (q < times + 1 && d < 8192);
        q = 0;//reset reps
    }
    else if (Y[a] != Y[a + 1])//if the 2 values are not the same interpolate between them
    {
        change = (Y[a] - Y[a + 1]);//work out difference between the values
        up = true;//the waveform is increasing
        if ((Y[a + 1] - Y[a]) > change)//if that number was a negative try the other way around
        {
            change = (Y[a + 1] - Y[a]);//work out difference bwteen values
            up = false;//the waveform is decreasing
        }
        points = (X[a] - X[a + 1]);//work out amount of time between given points
        if ((X[a + 1] - X[a]) > points)//if that was a negative try other way around
            points = (X[a + 1] - X[a]);///work out amount of time between given points
        pointchange = (change / points);//calculate the amount per point in time the value changes by
        if (points > 1)//any lower and the values cause errors
        {
            newy[d] = Y[a];//load first point
            d++;
            do
            {
                if (up == true)//
                    newy[d] = ((newy[d - 1]) + pointchange);
                else if (up == false)
                    newy[d] = ((newy[d - 1]) - pointchange);
                d++;
                q++;
            }
            while (q < points + 1 && d < 8192);
            q = 0;
        }
        else if (points != 0 && points > 0)
        {
            newy[d] = Y[a];//load first point
            d++;
        }
    }
    a++;
}
```

and this creates a close waveform but it is still very steppy.

So can anyone see why this isn't very accurate?
How to improve its accuracy?
Or a different way of doing this using arrays?

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Least Squares C# library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350852/least-squares-c-sharp-library)

Answer (score 20):

Try this method for me:

```
static public double linear(double x, double x0, double x1, double y0, double y1)
{
    if ((x1 - x0) == 0)
    {
        return (y0 + y1) / 2;
    }
    return y0 + (x - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0);
}
```

Effectively you should be able to take your arrays and use it like this:

```
var newY = linear(X[0], X[0], X[1], Y[0], Y[1]);
```

I pulled the code from [here](http://www.miltest.com/articles/application-notes/60-interpolation-in-csharp.html), but verified that the algorithm matched the theory [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), and so I ***think*** it's right. However, you probably should consider using polynomial interpolation if this is still steppy, please note the theory link, it shows that linear interpolation produces steppy waves.

So, the first link I gave, where I grabbed this code from, also has a polynomial algorithm:

```
static public double lagrange(double x, double[] xd, double[] yd)
{
    if (xd.Length != yd.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Arrays must be of equal length."); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = xd.Length; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (x - xd[i] == 0)
        {
            return yd[i];
        }
        double product = yd[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if ((i == j) || (xd[i] - xd[j] == 0))
            {
                continue;
            }
            product *= (x - xd[i]) / (xd[i] - xd[j]);
        }
        sum += product;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

To use this one you're going to have to decide how you want to step up your `x` values, so let's say we wanted to do it by finding the midpoint between the current iteration and the next:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X.Length; i++)
{
    var newY = lagrange(new double[] { X[i]d, X[i+1]d }.Average(), X, Y);
}
```

Please note that there will be more to this loop, like ensuring there is an `i+1` and such, but I wanted to see if I could give you a start.

Comment: so what value do i put into x ?
because its one of the unknowns isn't it?

Comment: return (y0 + y1) / 2 may throw an overflow exception if y0, y1 are large. You could fix this buy using y0 + (y1 - y0) /  2 instead.

Comment: product *= (x - xd[i]) / (xd[i] - xd[j]); first xd[i] must be xd[j] 
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/433b27e79887d28e6590657219ec0ff643a7fd84

Answer (score 3):

[Theoretical base at Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html)

**The solution below computes the averages of Y values for given points with same X, just as the Matlab polyfit function does**

*Linq and .NET framework version > 3.5 are mandatory for this swift API.*
Comments inside the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


/// <summary>
/// Linear Interpolation using the least squares method
/// <remarks>http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html</remarks> 
/// </summary>
public class LinearLeastSquaresInterpolation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// point list constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="points">points list</param>
    public LinearLeastSquaresInterpolation(IEnumerable<Point> points)
    {
        Points = points;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// abscissae/ordinates constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">abscissae</param>
    /// <param name="y">ordinates</param>
    public LinearLeastSquaresInterpolation(IEnumerable<float> x, IEnumerable<float> y)
    {
        if (x.Empty() || y.Empty())
            throw new ArgumentNullException("null-x");
        if (y.Empty())
            throw new ArgumentNullException("null-y");
        if (x.Count() != y.Count())
            throw new ArgumentException("diff-count");

        Points = x.Zip(y, (unx, uny) =>  new Point { x = unx, y = uny } );
    }

    private IEnumerable<Point> Points;
    /// <summary>
    /// original points count
    /// </summary>
    public int Count { get { return Points.Count(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// group points with equal x value, average group y value
    /// </summary>
                                                    public IEnumerable<Point> UniquePoints
{
    get
    {
        var grp = Points.GroupBy((p) => { return p.x; });
        foreach (IGrouping<float,Point> g in grp)
        {
            float currentX = g.Key;
            float averageYforX = g.Select(p => p.y).Average();
            yield return new Point() { x = currentX, y = averageYforX };
        }
    }
}
    /// <summary>
    /// count of point set used for interpolation
    /// </summary>
    public int CountUnique { get { return UniquePoints.Count(); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// abscissae
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<float> X { get { return UniquePoints.Select(p => p.x); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// ordinates
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<float> Y { get { return UniquePoints.Select(p => p.y); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// x mean
    /// </summary>
    public float AverageX { get { return X.Average(); } }
    /// <summary>
    /// y mean
    /// </summary>
    public float AverageY { get { return Y.Average(); } }

    /// <summary>
    /// the computed slope, aka regression coefficient
    /// </summary>
    public float Slope { get { return ssxy / ssxx; } }

    // dotvector(x,y)-n*avgx*avgy
    float ssxy { get { return X.DotProduct(Y) - CountUnique * AverageX * AverageY; } }
    //sum squares x - n * square avgx
    float ssxx { get { return X.DotProduct(X) - CountUnique * AverageX * AverageX; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// computed  intercept
    /// </summary>
    public float Intercept { get { return AverageY - Slope * AverageX; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("slope:{0:F02} intercept:{1:F02}", Slope, Intercept);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// any given point
/// </summary>
 public class Point 
 {
     public float x { get; set; }
     public float y { get; set; }
 }

/// <summary>
/// Linq extensions
/// </summary>
public static class Extensions 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// dot vector product
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">input</param>
    /// <param name="b">input</param>
    /// <returns>dot product of 2 inputs</returns>
    public static float DotProduct(this IEnumerable<float> a, IEnumerable<float> b)
    {
        return a.Zip(b, (d1, d2) => d1 * d2).Sum();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// is empty enumerable
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Empty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> a)
    {
        return a == null || a.Count() == 0;
    }
}
```

*Use it like:*

```
var llsi = new LinearLeastSquaresInterpolation(new Point[] 
    {
        new Point {x=1, y=1}, new Point {x=1, y=1.1f}, new Point {x=1, y=0.9f}, 
        new Point {x=2, y=2}, new Point {x=2, y=2.1f}, new Point {x=2, y=1.9f}, 
        new Point {x=3, y=3}, new Point {x=3, y=3.1f}, new Point {x=3, y=2.9f}, 
        new Point {x=10, y=10}, new Point {x=10, y=10.1f}, new Point {x=10, y=9.9f},
        new Point {x=100, y=100}, new Point{x=100, y=100.1f}, new Point {x=100, y=99.9f}
    });
```

*Or:*

```
var llsi = new LinearLeastSquaresInterpolation(
    new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
    new float[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
```

Comment: Did you write this? If not, where did it come from and what is the licensing on the code?

Comment: Yes. You can use it free of charge. It's a naive implementation based on least squares as referenced in that wolfram link